# Haproxy add response header for subdomain

Tags: http-headers, haproxy

I tried to add a header for a subdomain this way:

```
acl ExampleRule hdr(host) -i subdomain.example.com
http-response set-header X-test "test" if ExampleRule
```

But when I load the page it isn't added. Does anyone know how to add it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are two problems.

The first is that `http-response` and `hdr()`, together, would result in testing a response header, not a request header.

> `hdr([<name>[,<occ>]]) : string`
>
> This is equivalent to `req.hdr()` when used on requests, and to `res.hdr()` when
>   used on responses. Please refer to these respective fetches for more details.
>   In case of doubt about the fetch direction, please use the explicit ones.
>
> http://cbonte.github.io/haproxy-dconv/1.6/configuration.html#7.3.6-hdr

So, you'd want to use `req.hdr()`.

But that isn't enough, because regardless of declaration order, ACL condition evaluation is deferred, and done dynamically only if and when the statement referencing the ACL is encountered.

When the ACL is evaluated during response processing, `req.hdr()` will not match anything, because for efficiency, the request buffer is freed as soon as the request has been sent off to the server.  It isn't available during response processing, so no request fetches can return any values from it -- it's already been forgotten.

So, you need to capture the header in a transaction variable during request processing...

```
http-request set-var(txn.myhostheader) req.hdr(host)
```

...and then evaluate the variable's value during response processing.

```
acl ExampleRule var(txn.myhostheader) -i subdomain.example.com
http-response set-header X-test "test" if ExampleRule
```

Or those last two lines can be replaced with this one line (an anonymous ACL):

```
http-response set-header X-test "test" if { var(txn.myhostheader) -i subdomain.example.com }
```

In each case, the variable name is `txn.myhostheader` is `txn` (required) indicating a variable that retains its value for the duration of the request and response + `.` (required) + `myhostheader`, which is a name I made up.

Comment: I tested your solution and it works, thanks for the help!!